# How to access the database Remotely through IIS?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2005

I have used the ASP.net with C#. I want to access the SQL Server database through web server. When  executing my application from development area it's working but after deploy the application to the IIS server it shows the following exception:

> CREATE DATABASE permission denied in database 'master'. An attempt to
>   attach an auto-named database for file D:\newtest\newtest.mdf failed.
>   A database with the same name exists, or specified file cannot be
>   opened, or it is located on UNC share.

I have used the following connection string to attached with database

```
    Data Source = .\\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFileName=databasepath; Integrated Security=true
```

How do I access the SQL Server database Remotely through IIS?

Answer (score 0):

Hey Create Credential with SQL server and update your config file

```
connectionString="Data Source=Abcl\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=master;User ID=sa;Password=pwd12" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
```

if your are using db file like mdf
Pls use like this

```
connectionString="AttachDbFilename='C:\Documents and Settings\nmartin\My Documents\PS_Upload\TimeTrack\src\TimeTracker\TimeTrack\App_Data\ASPNETDB.MDF';Integrated Security=True; User Instance=True"
```

Comment: in my application there is no fixed database file , i change my database every time , i have pass one file in project folder file contains database path ,read the database path from this file how to pass the database path every time in web.config & i have used this connection string in class file & how to access the database without userID in ASP.net

Comment: hey i have updated my answer as base on your requirement ... pls check

Comment: I will have to suggest that `sa` is a bad example to use.

Comment: @ Aaron Bertrand its just example only, offcourse have to create own user name and password with rights of specifi database to use for specifi application

Comment: plz see my connection string in question same as your connection string ,i have write this in directly class file not in web.config

Answer (score 0):

Although the answer by Sanjay is correct, it doesn't really explain *why* you're getting the permission denied.

Code running in ASP.NET / IIS runs as a specific user, as defied in the worker process' config. For IIS 6 [Server 2003] (and below, I think) the default was `NETWORK SERVICE` for IIS 7+ [Server 2008], the default behavior is to run as a special application pool user `IISAPPPOOL\yourAppPoolName`.

If you grant the requisite permissions on your database for the correct user account(s) -- you should be able to get around the error and still use integrated security.

As an aside, it is generally a good idea to give the most restrictive (yet still operable) set of permissions on your database. `CREATE DATABASE` requires a pretty high permission level (I don't remember what off the top of my head.) If you grant that to your IIS application, you run a significant risk of allowing a less than honorable user taking control of your database system and wreaking havoc on it.

Answer (score 0):

They key is that you've used `Integrated Security=True` in your conneciton string.

When you run your project in your development environment, the web application usually runs as your local user account.  Furthermore, your account is usually a privileged user (admin) on the local SQL instance.

On your deployment server, IIS usually runs as a local machine account (or an account provisioned for your AppPool).  That account usually doesn't have any special privileges on the SQL server instace.

As debracey points out, you normally don't want to have your app's SQL privileges high enough to cause any harm (even if it's an honest mistake on your part).  One common pattern to avoid tihs is to have two separate SQL accounts for your app:

1. A high-priviledged account for creating and modifying your database schmea (e.g. db_owner role)
2. A limited-privilege account for accessing your database while your app runs (e.g. db_datareader and/or db_datawriter role)